# Using exceptions to break out of an iteration over the lines of a file

Tags: exception, ocaml

There are some text files which needed to be manipulated line by line. I wrote a `withFile` function as below:

```
let withFile fn handle =
    let rec iter_lines fh =
    try
        handle (input_line fh);
        iter_lines fh
    with _ -> close_in fh in
    iter_lines (open_in fn);;
```

So i can manipulate each file as :

```
withFile "file1.txt" (fun line -> (*...*))
withFile "file2.txt" (fun line -> (*...*))
...
```

But I am not sure how to exit elegantly when i do not want to handle all lines. For example:

```
withFile "file3.txt" (fun line ->
   (*when the line meets some condition, i will exit without handling other lines*)
);
```

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function `iter_lines` isn't tail recursive, which means you will probably exhaust your stack space if you process a very large file this way.  The reason it isn't tail recursive is that it has to establish and tear down the `try ... with` mechanism for catching exceptions.

Other than that, this looks really good to me.  This kind of higher-order function is what OCaml (and FP) is all about.

One way to make it tail recursive is to move the exception handling out to the containing function.  I would also be more specific about the exception that you want to handle.  So you get this:

```
let withFile fn handle =
    let rec iter_lines fh =
        handle (input_line fh);
        iter_lines fh
    in
    let fh = open_in fn in
    try iter_lines fh
    with End_of_file -> close_in fh
```

If you want to be able to exit early, one easy way is to have your handle function return a boolean that tells whether to continue processing lines or not.  You would end up with something like this:

```
let withFile fn handle =
    let rec iter_lines fh =
        if handle (input_line fh) then
            iter_lines fh
    in
    let fh = open_in fn in
    try iter_lines fh
    with End_of_file -> close_in fh
```

If you want to be able to use an exception to exit early, you'd need to catch *all* exceptions in `withFile`, close the file, then re-raise any exception other than `End_of_file`.  This gives you code that looks like this:

```
let withFile fn handle =
    let rec iter_lines fh =
        handle (input_line fh);
        iter_lines fh
    in
    let fh = open_in fn in
    try iter_lines fh
    with e ->
        (close_in fh; if e <> End_of_file then raise e)
```